# React / Express - How will server side rendering work with my dynamic pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, rss

So I am building an article based app using react and express.
My app consists of 3 static pages, and 1 dynamic article page.

At this moment in time, my article's data comes from an RSS feed. The dynamic article page displays different articles depending on which article RSS item is passed to it through props.

**My question is:**

How will SSR work with search engine crawlers to know my articles exist? so if I was to search for "My Site Article Foo" or "My Site Article Bar", how would it know that those different articles existed?

Because as it stands, the article's urls would be like so:

- www.mySite.com/articles?articleId=1
- www.mySite.com/articles?articleId=2
- www.mySite.com/articles?articleId=3

Even if I was not using an RSS feed, and simply using a database, how does this concept work?

---

Any help or advice is appreciated, Thank you in advance.

> PS. I was not sure if this was the correct stack exchange site to ask
>   on, if there is a better suited one, please let me know so I can move
>   this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pages should be indexed by crawlers if you have setup server-side rendering. Crawlers like Google's can now follow query parameters.

You can use the 'Fetch and Render' method of Google's Search Console to see the contents of your JS-based page.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/10/updating-our-technical-webmaster.html

Comment: Ahh that's cool, how do you know this? I would love to read up some more about it if you found this out online etc!

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your comment. This stuff is pretty cool!

Comment: Accepting the answer would help others in the future.